# Is there a way to use "from torchvision import transforms" to perform data augmentation for semantic segmentaion task in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, image-segmentation, data-augmentation, pytorch-dataloader

I have seen many examples with [*Albumentation*](https://albumentations.ai/docs/getting_started/image_augmentation/) library after writing own class for the custom data. However I dunno if we could do augmentation with [*transforms.compose()*](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.transforms.Compose.html) directly using PyTorch for images and corresponding labels, followed up with [*Dataloader*](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html). Any example code would be really helpful.

Comment: You might want have a look at the Transforms V2 API, as described in this blog post: https://pytorch.org/blog/extending-torchvisions-transforms-to-object-detection-segmentation-and-video-tasks/ As I understand it, it should support your use case of transforming pixel-wise labels.